# Как найти среднее значение для каждого id за 12 периодов для каждой колонки?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, обработка-данных

Есть такие данные из CSV файла:

[image: dataframe]

Как найти средние значение `future_0`...`future_49` за 12 периодов для каждого id?

[CSV файл с данными](https://mega.dp.ua/ru/GfwPH).

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл) и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: что значит найти средние `"за 12 периодов"` ?

Comment: найти средние значения featute_0-49 для каждого id

Comment: Замените пожалуйста картинку текстом. Если это вызывает у вас затруднение, то задайте новый вопрос - "Как скопровть данные текстом из инструмента XY?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

чтобы найти средние значения `featute_0`-`featute_49` для каждого `id` нужно просто избавиться от ненужного столбца `period`, сгруппировать фрейм по столбцу `id` и найти среднее для всех оставшихся столбцов:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\mega.dp.ua_tabular_data.csv")
res = df.drop(columns=["period"]).groupby("id").mean()
```

результат:

```
In [72]: res
Out[72]:
       feature_0   feature_1  feature_2    feature_3    feature_4  ...  feature_45  feature_46  feature_47  \
id                                                                 ...
0     110.000000   60.916667   0.238880   293.635812   430.134167  ...    0.750000    0.508078  142.833333
1     110.000000  135.541667   0.060443  6940.579852  1119.352500  ...    6.750000    0.331702  135.916667
2     110.166667    0.597500   5.203073     0.141369     4.168333  ...    0.000000    0.195109   10.083333
3     110.000000   62.500000   2.589315  1515.795679    75.613333  ...    1.000000    0.690459  106.000000
4     110.000000  126.000000   0.133693  2568.283478   460.332500  ...   36.333333    0.819175  190.333333
...          ...         ...        ...          ...          ...  ...         ...         ...         ...
5101  110.000000   94.166667   0.292280   180.142899  1218.388333  ...   12.083333         NaN  167.250000
5102  110.000000   80.675000   0.755737     0.000000   215.499167  ...    8.500000    0.453970  102.416667
5103  110.250000   22.568333   0.801533     0.000000   145.231667  ...    5.583333    0.352421   17.250000
5104  110.000000   86.230833   0.068594   988.894377    72.641667  ...    4.333333    0.714110   60.916667
5105  110.000000   76.458333        NaN     0.000000    83.882500  ...    0.166667    0.075049   43.666667

      feature_48  feature_49
id
0     315.011667    0.250000
1            NaN  204.334131
2       2.470000    0.000000
3      55.316667    6.666667
4            NaN  208.911004
...          ...         ...
5101  858.400833    6.500000
5102  187.505833    1.666667
5103         NaN    7.666667
5104   49.870833    4.583333
5105   58.860833    0.000000

[5106 rows x 49 columns]
```

Comment: у меня было примерно такое же решение только я не додумался до удаления `period`

Comment: @MaxU, можете помочь с Машинным Обучением в ЛС? https://t.me/mMRKSs

Comment: @Markys, нет, если в ЛС, то это уже менторство. Я не готов бесплатно этим заниматься ;) Можете поискать себе репетитора или ментора на соответствующей платформе...

Comment: @MaxU, давайте обсудим, я отблагодарю